# scikit-learn linear regression memory overflow for MNIST

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, scikit-learn, mnist

I am trying to perform basic linear regression of MNIST data using the scikit-learn module. It seems to crash with MemoryError. What am I doing wrong? The shape of the training dataset is (60000, 728)

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist
from sklearn import linear_model

(xTrain, yTrain), (xTest, yTest) = mnist.load_data()

xTrain2D = xTrain.reshape((len(xTrain), -1))
xTest2D = xTest.reshape((len(xTest), -1))

reg = linear_model.LinearRegression()
reg.fit(xTrain2D, yTrain)
```

Comment: The code you have posted runs OK in Google Colab. The error you (actually not) report cannot be reproduced.

Comment: @desertnaut Thanks for checking out! Probably my laptop is getting old...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the implementation of `sklearn` older versions of sklearn have this issue, the older versions have issues in resource management. Try upgrading `sklearn`.

Other viable option is to run this code in [kaggle](http://kaggle.com/) or [google colab](https://colab.research.google.com/).